# Error activating ShrePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature

Tags: feature-activation

I have installed SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise Edition in Windows Azure. After successful installation and configuration,I created a web application. When I tried to activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature, Site Setting -> Site Collection Features - > SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure - > Activate, it gave me an error:

> "Can not add a field without a Display Name."

[image]

I haven't explicitly added any lists or webparts to this site. Had tried to activate publishing feature on an blank site template.

Edit: Log entry tracked by correlation ID is:

> Medium        SPContentTypeBindingElement.ElementActivated(). Applying
>   ContentType
>   '0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC100E214EEE741181F4E9F7ACC43278EE811'
>   to list '_catalogs/masterpage' on web
>   'http://itplappsp01:8040' 7c909163-4c0d-4d30-a8ba-a55aa06d4143
>
> Unexpected    SPContentTypeBindingElement.ElementActivated(). An error
>   occurred binding content type
>   '0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC100E214EEE741181F4E9F7ACC43278EE811'
>   to list '/_catalogs/masterpage' on web 'http://itplappsp01:8040'. 
>   Exception 'Can not add a field without a Display
>   Name.'.   7c909163-4c0d-4d30-a8ba-a55aa06d4143
>
> High      The element of type 'ContentTypeBinding' for feature
>   'PublishingResources' (id: aebc918d-b20f-4a11-a1db-9ed84d79c87e) threw
>   an exception during activation: An error occurred binding content type
>   '0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC100E214EEE741181F4E9F7ACC43278EE811'
>   to list '/_catalogs/masterpage' on 'http://itplappsp01:8040'. 
>   Exception 'Can not add a field without a Display
>   Name.'.   7c909163-4c0d-4d30-a8ba-a55aa06d4143
>
> High      Feature Activation: Threw an exception, attempting to roll
>   back.  Feature 'PublishingResources' (ID:
>   'aebc918d-b20f-4a11-a1db-9ed84d79c87e').  Exception:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: An error occurred binding content
>   type
>   '0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC100E214EEE741181F4E9F7ACC43278EE811'
>   to list '/_catalogs/masterpage' on 'http://itplappsp01:8040'. 
>   Exception 'Can not add a field without a Display Name.'. --->
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Can not add a field without a
>   Display Name.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.AddFieldAsXmlInternal(String
>   schemaXml, Boolean addToDefaultView, SPAddFieldOptions op, Boolean
>   isMigration, Boolean fResetCTCol)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType.ProvisionFieldOnList(SPField field,
>   Boolean bRecurAllowed)     at
>   Microsoft...  7c909163-4c0d-4d30-a8ba-a55aa06d4143
>
> High      ....SharePoint.SPContentType.ProvisionFieldsOnList()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType.DeriveContentType(SPContentTypeCollection
>   cts, SPContentType& ctNew)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection.AddContentTypeToList(SPContentType
>   contentType)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection.AddContentType(SPContentType
>   contentType, Boolean updateResourceFileProperty, Boolean checkName,
>   Boolean setNextChildByte)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeBindingElement.EnsureContentTypeExists(SPWeb
>   web)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionContentTypeAndEventReceiverBindings(SPFeaturePropertyCollection
>   props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Admin... 7c909163-4c0d-4d30-a8ba-a55aa06d4143
>
> High
>     ...istration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection
>   props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean
>   fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite
>   siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props,
>   Boolean fForce)   7c909163-4c0d-4d30-a8ba-a55aa06d4143

Comment: could you coppy an error from ULS ? You can find this error by correlation ID.

Comment: I have edited the question with the entries in the log in 14 hive. Hope its what u meant. please excuse for am new to SP.

Comment: My suggestion is to use PowerShell to retrieve all site columns and find what column does not have display name, after this you can fix this name.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. Few of my custom list fields were missing display name. Fixing that solved the problem.